# R shiny app to visualize dataset after calculating mean

Tags: r, shiny

Using the fileInput function below, the user will input data in R shiny. Before the app visualizes data in the table panel, the app is generating new columns using the mutate function in tidyverse. Mean1 variable will be the mean of pay after grouping the data by venture and type. Mean2 will be the mean of pay after grouping venture, type, sectionnum. I would like to visualize this dataset generated on the shiny app in the main panel.

Example data:

```
Df <- structure(list(Venture = c("N", "N", "N", "N", "R", "R", "R", 
"R", "S", "S", "S", "S"), Type = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 
1, 2, 2), Section = c("Sect112", "Sect112", "Sect112", "Sect112", 
"Sect112", "Sect112", "Sect112", "Sect112", "Sect112", "Sect112", 
"Sect112", "Sect112"), Pay = c(102029, 102271, 679263, 669249, 
203499, 218765, 495000, 487562, 773432, 765423, 233345, 245690
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

```
ui <- fluidPage(
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            fileInput(inputId="files", label = "Select XLSX files", multiple = TRUE)),
        mainPanel(
            tabsetPanel(tabPanel("Table", tableOutput("table")))
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input,output){
    #Read in the files and rbind them
    data <- reactive({
        req(input$files)
        data <- lapply(input$files$datapath, read_xlsx)
        if(length(data) == 0) {
            return(data.frame()) 
        }
        data <- do.call(rbind, data)
        
    # data
    data %>% 
            filter(Venture %in%   c('N','R','S')) %>% 
            select(Venture, Type, `Pay`, `Section`) %>% 
            filter(Type %in% c('1','2')) %>% 
            mutate(Pay = as.numeric(Pay),
                   SectionNum = str_sub(Section, start=5, end=7)) %>%
            group_by(Venture, Type) %>%
            mutate(mean1=mean(Pay),
                   sd1=sd(Pay)) %>%
            group_by(Venture, Type, SectionNum) %>%
            mutate(mean2 = mean(Pay),
                   sd2=sd(Pay))

output$table <- renderDataTable({data})
    })
```

**Error:** Error in func(fname, ...) : app.R did not return a shiny.appobj object.

Comment: Could you please provide example data?

Comment: Df <- data.frame(
  Venture = c("N", "N", "N", "N", "R", "R", "R", "R", "S", "S", "S", "S"),
  Type = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2),
  Section = c("Sect112", "Sect112", "Sect112","Sect112","Sect112", "Sect112", "Sect112","Sect112","Sect112", "Sect112", "Sect112","Sect112"),
  Pay = c(102029, 102271, 679263, 669249, 203499, 218765, 495000,487562,773432,765423,233345,245690)
)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tweaked your code in minor positions, this should work: One of the issues is the additional `})` in the end of server part:

Note I wrote a xlsx with the provided example data to the root folder:

```
Df <- data.frame( Venture = c("N", "N", "N", "N", "R", "R", "R", "R", "S", "S", "S", "S"), 
                  Type = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2), 
                  Section = c("Sect112", "Sect112", "Sect112","Sect112","Sect112", "Sect112", "Sect112","Sect112","Sect112", "Sect112", "Sect112","Sect112"), Pay = c(102029, 102271, 679263, 669249, 203499, 218765, 495000,487562,773432,765423,233345,245690)) 

library(openxlsx)
write.xlsx(Df, "Df")
```

then:

```
library(shiny)
library(openxlsx)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput(inputId = "files", label = "Select XLSX files", multiple = TRUE)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(tabPanel("Table", dataTableOutput("table")))
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  data <- reactive({
    req(input$files)
    data <- lapply(input$files$datapath, read.xlsx)
    if(length(data) == 0) {
      return(data.frame()) 
    }
    data <- do.call(rbind, data)
    
    data %>% 
      filter(Venture %in%   c('N', 'R', 'S')) %>% 
      select(Venture, Type, `Pay`, `Section`) %>% 
      filter(Type %in% c('1', '2')) %>% 
      mutate(Pay = as.numeric(Pay),
             SectionNum = str_sub(Section, start = 5, end = 7)) %>%
      group_by(Venture, Type) %>%
      mutate(mean1 = mean(Pay),
             sd1 = sd(Pay)) %>%
      group_by(Venture, Type, SectionNum) %>%
      mutate(mean2 = mean(Pay),
             sd2 = sd(Pay))
  })
  
  output$table <- renderDataTable({
    data()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Great, @TarJae this works. I was using 'dataTableOutput' in the server function incorrectly.